# Applying function to each key in a object inside array

Tags: jsonata

I have the following json:

```json
{
  "result": [
      {
          "codigo_produto": "10162",
          "gtin": "0000040084107",
          "descricao_produto": "Kinder Ovo",
          "un_venda": "UN",
          "segmento_1": "10000",
          "cod_segmento_1": "Geral"
      },
      {
          "codigo_produto": "185680",
          "gtin": "7892840127114",
          "descricao_produto": "Pingo D'ouro Picanha 65gr",
          "un_venda": "UN",
          "segmento_1": "10000",
          "cod_segmento_1": "Geral"
      }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to apply the function `$replace($value, /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/, '')` to every key in the objects that are inside the array to make sure that no special characters exist in every value of the object.

I have tried the following:

```
$ ~> | result |  
    $each(
        function($object) {
            $each($object, function($k, $v) {
                {$k: $replace($v, /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/, '') }
            })
        } 
    ) ~> $merge() |
```

But it gives the error `Argument 1 of function "each" does not match function signature`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a map operation and then $each + $merge pair:

```
result.(
  $each($, function($v, $k) {
    { $k: $replace($v, /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/, '') }
  }) ~> $merge()
)
```

Check it out on the playground: https://stedi.link/ouranAW

Answer (score 0):

*Hope This will Work*

```
  $ ~> | result |  
        $map(
            function($object) {
                {
                    $merge(
                        $object,
                        $map(
                            function($value, $key) {
                                { ($key): $replace($value, /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/, '') }
                            },
                            $object
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: This gives the error `Expected ":", got "}"`